# Discrepancy between two (seemingly) identical cache-hit-ratio queries

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I'm trying to assess the performance of a Postgres 10.6 instance. The first query below returns 0.88, the second one 0.77. **Whence the discrepancy between these two queries for the cache hit-ratio?**

```sql
SELECT sum(blks_hit) / sum(blks_hit + blks_read)
FROM pg_stat_database 
WHERE datname = 'the_current_db';
```

```sql
-- While connected to `the_current_db`, as above.
SELECT sum(heap_blks_hit) / sum(heap_blks_hit + heap_blks_read)
FROM pg_statio_all_tables;
```

For `pg_stat_database`, [the docs say](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-PG-STAT-DATABASE-VIEW):

> `blks_read bigint`
>
> Number of disk blocks read in this database

> `blks_hit bigint`
>
> Number of times disk blocks were found already in the buffer cache, so that a read was not necessary (this only includes hits in the PostgreSQL buffer cache, not the operating system's file system cache)

While the docs for [`pg_statio_all_tables`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-PG-STATIO-ALL-TABLES-VIEW):

> `heap_blks_read bigint`
>
> Number of disk blocks read from this table

> `heap_blks_hit bigint`
>
> Number of buffer hits in this table

(All the documentation links are for version 13, as it has more granular intra-page linking than version 10.)

Comment: pg_statio_all_tables shows only data for the current tables, not the ones that are dropped.

Comment: Would then `pg_statio_all_tables` be preferred source of measurements, when assessing "live" performance? And would the above queries return the same after a `VACUUM FULL`?

Comment: Also, where is this documented, that `pg_stat_database` also includes dropped tables (and `pg_statio_all_tables` not)?